# Grabbing data (.txt) from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have some scheduled batch jobs running automatically during the night and will show the results in separate .txt files. 
Is there anyway to grab the data from the .txt file and consolidate them to display in kibana?

Here is an example of .txt files (Windows)

Job Code.txt

```
job_id:0001,description:Ship data from server to elknode1
job_id:0002,description:Ship data from server to elknode2
job_id:0003,description:Ship data from server to elknode3
job_id:0004,description:Ship data from server to elknode4
```

Job Status.txt

```
job_id:0001,result:OK
job_id:0002,result:Error: Msg...
job_id:0003,result:OK
job_id:0004,result:OK
```

Here is the filter prt of my very basic logstash.conf file.

```
filter{
    grok{   match => {"message" => ["JobID: %{NOTSPACE:job_id}","description: %{NOTSPACE:description}","result: %{NOTSPACE:message}"]}
        add_field => {
            "JobID" => "%{job_id}"
            "Description" => "%{description}"
            "Message" => "%{message}"
        }
    }
    if [job_id] == "0001" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{job_id}"
            code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
        map_action => "create"
        }
    }
    if [job_id] == "0003" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{job_id}"
            code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
        map_action => "update"
        }
    }
    if [job_id] == "0002" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{job_id}"
            code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
        map_action => "update"
        }
    }
    if [job_id] == "0004" {
        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{job_id}"
            code => "map['time_elasped']=0"
            map_action => "update"
            end_of_task => true
            timeout => 120
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
However, I couldn't create any fields as seen and no message is combined.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind showing how your txt file looks like (few sample lines)?

Comment: Yea, I have amended the question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you have two files with the exact same number of lines but no shared ID between both (except the line number)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if your job would also output the Job ID in the `Job Status.txt` file?

Comment: I have tried to amend my codes and the outcome is still not satisfactory. Any advice?